# How to deal with permissions using docker - nginx / php-fpm

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a very simple Symfony application using nginx & php-fpm via Docker.

Two docker services :
1. web : running nginx
2. php : running php-fpm; containing application source.

I want to build images that can be deployed without any external dependency.
That's why I'm copying source code within the **php container**.
On development process; i'm overriding **/var/www/html** volume with local path.

```
# file: php-fpm/Dockerfile
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

COPY ./vendor /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

VOLUME /var/www/html
```

Now the docker-compose configuration file.

```
# file : docker-compose-prod.yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: "private/web"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes_from:
      - php
  php:
    image: "private/php"
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
```

The problem is about permissions.
When accessing localhost, Symfony is botting up, but **cache** / **logs** / **sessions** folders are not writable.

1. nginx is using **/var/www/html** to serve static files.
2. php-fpm is using **/var/www/html** to execute php files.

I'm not sure about the problem. 
But how can I be sure about the following:

1. **/var/www/html** have to be readable for nginx ?
2. **/var/www/html** have to be writable for php-fpm ?

Note: I'm building images from MacbookPro; **cache / logs / sessions** are 777.

Comment: What does `volumes_from` do, if you don't have any volumes specified in the `php` service?

Answer (score 7):

docker-compose.yml supports a [`user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) directive under services. The docs only mention it in the `run` command, but it works the same.

I have a similar setup and this is how I do it:

```
# file : docker-compose-prod.yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: "private/web"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes_from:
      - php
  php:
    image: "private/php"
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    user: "$UID"
```

I have to run `export UID` before running `docker-compose` and then that sets the default user to my current user. This allows logging / caching etc. to work as expected.

Comment: I was wondering how to make this solution current by removing volumes_from and using version 3 volume config.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution "Docker for Symfony" https://github.com/StaffNowa/docker-symfony

New features on

```
./d4d start
./d4s stop
./d4d help
```

Answer (score -2):

I've found a solution;
But if someone can explain best practices, it will be appreciate !

Folders **cache / logs / sessions** from docker context where not empty (on host).
Now that folders have been flushed, Symfony creates them with good permissions.

I've found people using **usermod** to change UID, ie: 1000 for www-data / nginx ...
But it seems to be an ugly hack. What do you think about ?

Comment: If you have a working solution, it would be good if you could share it :) I would expect that at least some code needs to be copied into the nginx image too.

Comment: That's pretty useless